# How to filter sqlalchemy table by values from python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Given the dict with status and value, I want to filter table rows:

```
my_join_data = [
    {
        "status": "status0",
        "value": 20,
    },
    {
        "status": "status1",
        "value": 25,
    },
]
```

Table values:

```
id  status   value
 0  status0     10
 1  status0     25
 2  status0     30
 3  status1     10
 4  status1     35
```

The my_join_data is taken from external source, so it cannot be stored to database.
I want to transform my_join_data to sqlalchemy table-like object, so I can do join and filtering afterward in a way equivalent to:

```
joined_table = my_table.join(
    my_join_data,
    my_join_data.c.status == my_table.c.status
)

query = sqlalchemy.select([
    my_table.c.id,
    my_table.c.status,
    my_table.c.value,
]).select_from(
    joined_table
).where(
    my_join_data.c.value < my_table.c.value
)
```

The expected result is

```
id  status   value
 1  status0     25
 2  status0     30
 4  status1     35
```

Is there any way to achieve this? The database is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter a SQL table in a sqlalchemy statement using a table from outside of the database without uploading it or writing a convoluted case statement.

You can load both the join_data and SQL table into Pandas DataFrames and then join and filter.

First I would condense the list of dictionaries into one dict.

```
status_list = []
value_list = []

for dict in my_join_data:
   status_list.append(dict["status"])
   value_list.append(dict["value"])

join_dict = {'status': status_list, 'value': value_list}
```

Then read both into a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

join_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(join_dict)
sql_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

Then merge the two and filter.

```
merged_df = sql_df.merge(join_df, how='left', on='status', suffixes=('', '_filter'))
filtered_df = merged_df.loc[merged_df['value_filter'] < merged_df['value']]
filtered_df.drop(columns='value_filter')
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than getting the data from database and then for-loop the result to apply filters?